# After installing mongoDB 3.4, mongod still runs old version of mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I just installed mongoDB v3.4 on my mac using homebrew however when I run mongod from terminal it still run the old v2.6 mongoDB.  What do I need to do to fix this?

Comment: how did you check the version of mongodb running?

Comment: When I ran mongod it says which version of mongo is running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to run

```
brew link --overwrite mongodb
```

Comment: Man, u saved me a day of headache.. I would upvote 100times if i could.